# How to write it in skolem form?(Prolog)

Tags: prolog

Translate the following formula into a horn formula in Skolem form:

∀w¬∀x∃z(H(w)∧(¬G(x,x)∨¬H(z)))

it's translated from german to english, how to write it in horn form and then in skolem form, i didn't find anything on internet...plz help me

Comment: Some Wiki pointers: [Skolem Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form) [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) [Horn Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause). They all have German versions too, although of varying quality.

Comment: Also: do you want to refute or prove this formula? In the first case, you directly apply the CNF transformation and skolemization. In the second case, you need to negate the formula first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will always use the satisfiability preserving version of skolemization, i.e. the one where those are replaced which would become existential quantifiers when moved to the head of the formula.

To make life a bit simpler, let's push the negations to the atoms. We can also see that w doesn't occur in ¬G(x,x)∨¬H(z) and that x,z don't occur in H(w), allowing us to distribute the quantifiers a bit inside.

Then we obtain the formula ∀w¬H(w) ∨ ∃x∀z (G(x,x)∧ H(z)) .

- If we want to refute the formula:

We skolemize ∃x and delete ∀w, ∀z and obtain:

¬H(w) ∨ (G(c,c)∧ H(z))

after CNF transformation, we have:

(¬H(w) ∨ G(c,c)) ∧ (¬H(w) ∨ H(z))

both clauses have exactly one positive literal, so they are horn clauses. Translated to Prolog syntax we get:

```
g(c,c) :- h(W).
h(Z) :- h(W).
```

- If we want to prove the formula:

We have to negate before we skolemize, leading to:

∃w H(w) ∧ ∀x∃z (¬G(x,x) ∨ ¬H(z))

after skolemizing ∃w and ∃z, deleting ∀x and CNF transformation, we obtain:

H(c) ∧ (¬G(x,x) ∨ ¬H(f(x)))

That could be interpreted as a fact `h(c)` and a query `?- g(X,X), h(f(X)).`

To be honest, both variants don't make much sense - the first does not terminate for any input and in the second version, the query will fail because `g/2` is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

does this page help?

[6.3 Convert first-order logic expressions to normal form](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/logic_topics/normal_forms/normal_form.html)

Answer (score 0):

A horn clause consists of various goals that all have to be satisfied in order for the whole clause to be true.

`∀w¬∀x∃z(H(w)∧(¬G(x,x)∨¬H(z)))`

First you want to translate the whole statement to human language for clarity. ¬ means NOT, ∧ means AND and ∨ means OR. The () are used to group goals.

`∀w¬∀x∃z`

For all w, all NOT x, at least 1 Z. If a w is true, x must be false and there must be at least 1 z.

`H(w)`

Is w a H? There must be a fact that says H(w) is true in your knowledge base.

`¬G(x,x)`

Is there a fact G(x,x)? If yes, return false.

`¬H(z)`

Is there a fact H(z)? If yes, return false.

`z(H(w)∧(¬G(x,x)∨¬H(z)))`

What this says that z is only true if H(w) is true AND either G(x,x) OR H(z) is false.

In Prolog you'd write this as
`factCheck(W,X,Z) :- h(W), not(g(X,X);not(checkZ(Z)).`
where Z is a list with at least 1 entry in it. If ANY element in list Z is true, fail.

```
%is the list empty?
checkZ([])
%is h true for the first element of the list?
checkZ([Head|Tail]) :- h(Head), !.
%remove the first element of the list
checkZ([Head|Tail]) :- checkZ(Tail).
```

Comment: You are disregarding the different nature of the quantifiers (∀,∃) in your explanation. To preserve satisfiability, it is necessary to introduce skolem terms for existential quantifiers. To preserve validity, it is necessary to introduce skolem terms for universal quantifiers.

Comment: To my knowledge Prolog uses Skolemization out of the box. Variable Z unifies with a list of other Variables, each which can unify with complex terms. How the term is specifically checked against a goal has to be defined  in a rule, consisting of facts somewhere in the knowledge base. Say the first element of a list is `a(b(c(d)))` then prolog checks for `h(a(b(c(d)))`.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Prolog only accepts skolemized Horn clauses as input, that's why there is no built-in way of writing a quantified formula. Even the negation operator ```\+``` is [Negation as Failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure), not classical negation. Many of these complications can be already dealt with when you transform your formula into Horn clauses, but it's not done automatically.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x ah I see now. I started Prolog before I started first order Logic so I will research skolemization further and expand on what I've said so far in order to expand and clarify the answer. There's more to this inversion of statements than I initially thought.

Comment: I didn't want to put the answer in before a few days had passed, in the hope that OP tried to solve it by themselves, but I added it now, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, I am kind of struggling with it. It's easy enough to push the NOT statements in to create the opposite, but how that exactly proves existence of a set is confusing the hell out of me. Upboated! I'll try and update my answer too, it's just not clicking in my brain yet. I've been staring at this subject for days now. So you make a rule for each term in the left part of the existence claim? I'm still not getting how the inversion of ∃ as "there exists" turns into ∀. I need to read more I think. For all ∀z there exists z that are either x or w?

Comment: Perhaps I should add the actual rule: ¬∀xF(x) is equivalent to ∃x ¬F(x) -- if F(x) does hold for all x, there must be (at least) one term t where F(t) does not hold. In classical logic, this means that ¬F(t) is true. It works similarly for ¬∃xF(x) and ∀x¬F(x) .

Comment: My apologies, it must read "if F(x) does _not_ hold for all x".

Comment: @lambda.xy.x - Oooh that makes sense. Not all x are F(x) so there exists at least 1 x that is not F(x). Fascinating.